# using group by in linq query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have following linq query in which i want to use group by clause.

```
var objList = from o in db.sometable1
            join p in db.sometable2 on o.someid equals p.Id
            join q in db.sometable3 on p.someid equals q.Id
            join r in db.sometable4 on p.someid equals r.Id
            join s in db.soetable5 on o.someid equals s.Id
            --group o by o.someid // what i am tru=ying
            select new
            {                
                  o.Id,
                  r.somecolumn,
                  r.somecolumn,
                  s.Name,
                  o.somecolumn,
                  p.somecolumn,
                  q.somecolumn,
                  r.somecolumn
            };
```

I want to get only distinct records from sometable1 on basis of a column(someId) in that table. But I am not able to achieve this. If anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you're using LINQ-to-SQL, so can simplify a lot of the `join`s:

```
var objList = from o in db.SomeTable1
              select new
              {
                    o.Id,
                    o.SomeTable4.SomeColumn1,
                    o.SomeTable4.SomeColumn2,
                    o.SomeTable5.Name,
                    o.SomeColumn,
                    o.SomeTable2.SomeColumn,
                    o.SomeTable3.SomeColumn,
                    o.SomeTable4.SomeColumn3,
              };
```

See [Querying Across Relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386932(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Navigate > Join](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/).

Now for the grouping:

```
var groups = from o in db.SomeTable1
             group new
             {   
                 o.Id,
                 o.SomeTable4.SomeColumn1,
                 o.SomeTable4.SomeColumn2,
                 o.SomeTable5.Name,
                 o.SomeColumn,
                 o.SomeTable2.SomeColumn,
                 o.SomeTable3.SomeColumn,
                 o.SomeTable4.SomeColumn3,
             } by o.SomeId;
```

This returns `IQueryable<IGrouping<some-id-type, anonymous-type>>`, which you can use as follows:

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var someId = group.Key; // the original SomeId property
    var theOnlyRecord = group.SingleOrDefault(); // this will throw if more than one record matches someId
}
```

This assumes there is only one record that matches each value of `SomeId`, thus `SingleOrDefault`; if there can be more than one, you'll have to apply some sort of selection mechanism of your own, the most straightforward of which would be replacing `SingleOrDefault` with `FirstOrDefault` to simply take the first of the duplicates for each value of `SomeId`.

Answer (score -1):

First way to achieve the requirement is make use of MoreLinq Library, which support function called DistinctBy in which you can specify the property on which you want to find Distinct objects.

```
var objList = from o in db.sometable
            join p in db.sometable2 on o.someid equals p.Id
            join q in db.sometable3 on p.someid equals q.Id
            join r in db.sometable4 on p.someid equals r.Id
            join s in db.soetable5 on o.someid equals s.Id
            --group o by o.someid // what i am tru=ying
            select new
            {                
                  o.Id,
                  r.somecolumn,
                  r1.somecolumn,
                  s.Name,
                  o1.somecolumn,
                  p.somecolumn,
                  q.somecolumn,
                  r2.somecolumn
            }.DistinctBy(x=>new{x.o,x.r,x.r1,x.s,x.o1,x.p,x.q,x.r2});
```

Comment: MoreLinq is LINQ-to-Objects ... OP clearly tagged question LINQ-to-SQL